# Why won't my floats fill up the available space on the page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to relocate a couple items on my page to fill up unused space on the page.

A float should be able to do the trick but for some reason they refuse to fill up the available space.

These items are placed inside the same direct parent.

```
<div class="image-div"></div>
<h1 class="title">title</h1>
<p class="description">Description</p>
<a class="download-link">download-link</a>
```

And have the following css.

```
.image-div {
     float: left;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 30%;
     margin-right: 5%;
     padding: 0;
}

.title,
.description,
.download-link {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Am I missing something? Advice would be much appreciated.

Also if there's an alternative way to achieve the same result I'd love to hear it.

I have tried position: absolute; but this messes up the page when the image gets too tall or when the description isn't long enough.

Answer (score 2):

Because you missed the classes for the title, description and link. Else it works.

```css
.image-div {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    padding: 0;
}

.title,
.description,
.download-link {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image-div"></div>
<h1 class="title">title</h1>
<p class="description">Description</p>
<a class="download-link">download-link</a>
```

Comment: Oops I actually do have the correct classes set but I forgot to add classes in the example, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are *horrible* to work with and can cause annoying layout issues that require a [clearfix](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) hack. Consider using [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) for this instead. Its [well-supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and is really... *flexible*.

Here's a quick example of how you might do this.

See Chris Coyier's excellent [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn more.

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.image-div {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.words-div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-div">img here</div>
  <div class="words-div">
    <h1 class="title">title</h1>
    <p class="description">Description</p>
    <a class="download-link">download-link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually my preferred method but since I'm modifying a Woocommerce template I have to admit that I'm unsure how to add a parent div to the text items as they are all placed using hooks. This is still quite new to me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I removed the floats from the text div's (right side). I got them right where I wanted. This is the css that worked for me:

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery {
 float: left;
 width: 25%;
 margin: 0 5% 1.41575em 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.entry-title,
.product_title,
.woocommerce-product-details__short-description,
.product_attachments {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```